# IF I click on The Image Icon, Icon should be clickable and A popup[Dialogue Box] should open to upload new image

Tags: html, css, angular

IF I click on The Image Icon, Icon  should be clickable and  A popup[Dialogue Box] should open to upload new image ...[Sample Image for your reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4e4R.png) 
please help me in this thanks in advance

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-start summary" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">

                <img src="https://www.bpimaging.com/assets/uploads/2015/02/business-portrait-photography-man.jpg" style="width: 56px;max-height: 56px;clip-path: circle(22px at center);"
                    class="mr-3 d-none d-sm-block" alt="...">
                <i *ngIf="isEditItems"  style="color : white;left: 52px;
                    position: absolute; top: 65px; padding: 3px; background-color: rgb(0, 195, 255); border-radius: 50%;font-size: 12px;"
                    class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i>

                <div>

                    <div class="summary-details">This is a sample text. You can upload your profile picture here. This
                        will be visible to all clients in your contact information. You can change it again if you
                        want.

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: you can use an `hidden` inuput box binded tho the image click to achieve that.

Comment: Hi Jacopo , Thanks for the reply ... Can u type the code what u r saying for that ?

Comment: Do you want to open bootstrap modal popup on click image??

Comment: Yes I need that , Please help me in this

Comment: @Sundeep, Is this what you need?? https://www.bootply.com/fzlrwIyyXK If you click the image you can get the popup with upload image in it..

Comment: @ undefined... YES

Comment: @Sundeep, I have posted it as answer, Kindly accept it as it solves your issue..

Comment: Ok Thank you  @Undefined

Comment: @Undefined , Yes I selected the tock mark ,but it is not showing here

Comment: @undefined donhe

Comment: @Sundeep, Glad to help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using bootstrap, for popup you can use bootstrap modal..

In your html make the following changes,

Add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"`

```
<img src="https://www.bpimaging.com/assets/uploads/2015/02/business-portrait-photography-man.jpg" style="width: 56px;max-height: 56px;clip-path: circle(22px at center);" class="mr-3 d-none d-sm-block" alt="..." data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
```

Then include the following,

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">

      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Profile information</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="custom-file">
    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
  </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
```

A **working example** is here https://www.bootply.com/fzlrwIyyXK

Answer (score 0):

You can have this simple html. the class `file-hidden` is just a `display:none`

```
<div class="some-class">
  <img src="app/img/your-image.png" (click)="uploader.click()"/>
  <input #uploader class="file-hidden" type="file" accept="image/*" value=""  (change)="getDataFromImageSelection($event)">
</div>
```

then via ts

```
getDataFromImageSelection(fileInput: any, guid, index){
    if(fileInput.target.files.length > 0){
      let file = fileInput.target.files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this); // <-- this is async
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  }

_handleReaderLoaded(readerEvt) {
    var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
    this.base64textString= btoa(binaryString);
    if(!!this.base64textString){
      // Do your stuff with the base64 
    }
}
```

I personally use this code in my app and it's working fine. Sadly I can't show you more code on the `if(!!this.base64textString)` part because it's just a service call that store the image in a database.